# Twitter API in SWIFT via Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, api, twitter

I currently try to send a simple query - in Postman it works fine for me, but in SWIFT I simply cant get it working
My Code looks like:

```
func TWITTER_getPosts(username:String){


        let headers = [
            "screen_name": "username",
            "authorization": "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"<KEY>\",oauth_token=\"<KEY>\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp=\"1469246792\",oauth_nonce=\"n6Sxbq\",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=\"<KEY>\"",
            "include_rts": "false"
        ]

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json", parameters: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
        }
    }
```

I Always end in a

> errors =     (
>                   {
>               code = 215;
>               message = "Bad Authentication data.";

Comment: have you tried using STTwitter https://cocoapods.org/pods/STTwitter ? I don't have experience using it in Swift but it might prove helpful if it's bridgeable

Comment: How can we generate signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the parameters for the request method is incorrect.
If you are passing headers, they shouldn't be passed in parameters, they should be passed as the following:

```
let headers = [
 "Authorization": "Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==",
 "Accept": "application/json"
]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", headers: headers)
     .responseJSON { response in
         debugPrint(response)
     }
```

`headers: headers` should be the way to go.